# assigning array to kendo menuitem?

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, kendo-ui, kendo-menu

I have been using a template for kendo menu i need to push the menu items dynamically so i have used a array like called "dt"

now i am having problem in assigning this array "dt" to the menu item

so,please suggest me how to assign a array for the kendo menuitem

```
dt=[];
  dt.push({
        text: "Prsenations",
        template: template,

        presecontent: "PresentaionContent",
        preview: "prviewbutton",

        encoded: false,

    });


 $("#menuitem").kendoMenu({
        dataSource: transformText([
        {
            text: "Presentations",
            items: dt,

        }
        ])
    });
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: it is not showing me particular error but the page and the controls in the page are not loaded.

Comment: I don't know what the code was for `template:template`. So I commented it. There might be some problem there.

Answer (score 0):

[Try this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BW9rK/)

```
var menu = $("#menu").kendoMenu().data("kendoMenu");
dt=[];
dt.push({
    text: "Prsenations",
   // template: template,

    presecontent: "PresentaionContent",
    preview: "prviewbutton",

    encoded: false

});


$("#menu").kendoMenu({
    dataSource: [
    {
        text: "Presentations",
        items: dt

    }
    ]
});
```